# How to do pagination of columns in Full Calendar?

Tags: jquery, pagination, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using [FullCalender](https://fullcalendar.io/) library. I need to use [Vertical Resource View of fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view) to display the resources as columns. Now, in the grid, I have to work with large number of resources and the grid may have 50-100 columns.

[image]

As we can see in the above grid, we have only 23 resources and the columns become very congested. 
But, I want to see 5 at a time. On the first time load, the grid will show 1-5 columns. There will be a next button and if I click, the grid will show 6-10 columns, then 11-15 and so on.

Code of calendar above given below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
     header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: ''
     },
    plugins: [ 'resourceTimeGrid' ],
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    defaultView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
    resources: [
      { id: '1', title: 'Room 1' },
      { id: '2', title: 'Room 2'},
      { id: '3', title: 'Room 3' },
      { id: '4', title: 'Room 4' },
      { id: '5', title: 'Room 5' },
      { id: '6', title: 'Room 6'},
      { id: '7', title: 'Room 7' },
      { id: '8', title: 'Room 8' },
      { id: '9', title: 'Room 9' },
      { id: '10', title: 'Room 10'},
      { id: '11', title: 'Room 11' },
      { id: '12', title: 'Room 12' },
      { id: '13', title: 'Room 13' },
      { id: '14', title: 'Room 14'},
      { id: '15', title: 'Room 15' },
      { id: '16', title: 'Room 16' },
      { id: '17', title: 'Room 17'},
      { id: '18', title: 'Room 18' },
      { id: '19', title: 'Room 19' },
      { id: '20', title: 'Room 20' },
      { id: '21', title: 'Room 21'},
      { id: '22', title: 'Room 22' },
      { id: '23', title: 'Room 23' },
    ],
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources=4&single-day'
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

**Is there any way to do the column pagination in Full Calendar?**

Comment: There's no built-in funtionality for it no, you'll have to write your own logic to show and hide resources.

Comment: @ADyson, Thanks for identifying the mistake of posting the identical question. This happened because of miscommunication.  
I contacted Setu Kumar Basak about this question.